# Invoke a private macro within a quote block

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I'm trying to invoke a private macro, within a quote block, using a variable defined within the code block itself.
This is the pseudo-code showing what I would like to do (doesn't work)

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacrop debug(msg) do
    quote bind_quoted: [msg: msg], do: IO.puts(msg)
  end

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def hello do
        my = "testme"

        unquote(debug(quote do: my))
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule Bar do
  use Foo
end

Bar.hello()
```

And this would get converted (in my mind), at compile time to:

```
defmodule Bar do
  def hello do
    my = "testme"
    IO.puts(my)
  end
end
```

Is there any way to achieve this? I'm struggling to find any documentation related to it.

**Update**

I discovered that:

```
defmodule Foo do
  defmacrop debug() do
    quote do: IO.puts("hello")
  end

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def hello do
        my = "testme"

        unquote(debug())
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Gets properly converted to what I need, but I'm struggling find a way to pass the variable as is, so that it becomes `IO.puts(my)`

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is with nested quoting: the private macro should return the double-quoted expression (since to invoke it from the outer scope one needs to explicitly `unquote`, and macro is still expected to return a quoted expression.)

*Sidenote:* your *update* section is *wrong*; you might notice, that `"hello"` is printed during a compilation stage, namely when `use Foo` is being compiled. That is because the double-quoting is needed, the code in your *update* section executes `IO.puts` when `unquote` in `__using__` macro is met.

On the other hand, `my` should be quoted only once. That might be achieved with an explicit quoting of *AST*, passing the `msg` there *as is*:

```rb
defmodule Foo do
  defmacrop debug(msg) do
    quote bind_quoted: [msg: msg] do
      {
        {:., [], [{:__aliases__, [alias: false], [:IO]}, :puts]},
        [],
        [msg]} # ⇐ HERE `msg` is the untouched argument
    end 
  end 

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    quote do
      def hello do
        my = "testme"

        unquote(debug(quote do: my))
      end 
    end 
  end 
end

defmodule Bar do
  use Foo 
end

Bar.hello()
#⇒ "testme"
```

I was unable to achieve the same functionality with options in the call to [`Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2-options); the only available related option is `unquote` to tune the *unquoting* inside nested quotes, while we need the exact opposite.

---

*Sidenote:* below does not work and I expect this to be a bug in [`Kernel.SpecialForms.quote/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#quote/2) implementation.

```rb
quote bind_quoted: [msg: msg] do
  quote bind_quoted: [msg: msg], do: IO.puts(msg)
end
```

FWIW: I [filed an issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/7709).

I believe it might be a good feature request to Elixir core, to allow an option that disables additional *quoting*.

---

*Sidenote 2:* the following works (**most concise approach**):

```rb
defmacrop debug(msg) do
  quote bind_quoted: [msg: msg] do
    quote do: IO.puts(unquote msg)
  end
end
```

So you might avoid tackling with an explicit AST and just use the above. I am leaving the answer as is, since dealing with AST directly is also a very good option, that should be used as a sledgehammer / last resort, which does always work.

---

If `IO.puts` is not your desired target, you might call `quote do: YOUR_EXPR` on what you want to have in `debug` macro:

```rb
quote do: to_string(arg)
#⇒ {:to_string, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [{:arg, [], Elixir}]}
```

and manually unquote the `arg` in the result:

```rb
#                                             ✗  ⇓⇓⇓ {:arg, [], Elixir} 
#                                             ✓  ⇓⇓⇓ arg
{:to_string, [context: Elixir, import: Kernel], [arg]}
```

This is basically how I got the AST of your original request (`IO.puts`.)